# How to run a Neo4j Destop graph database from command line?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I created two graph db's with Neo4J Desktop.
Now I want to run them at the same time, on different ports.
The two databases have been saved by Neo4j Desktop respectively in the folders:

- `Neo4j\ Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-1/installation-3.5.5/`
- `Neo4j\ Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-2/installation-3.5.5/`

Looking at the settings in the Neo4j Desktop (the `neo4j.conf` file), the first graph uses the ports 11213, 11214 and 11215.
The second uses the default ports.

I downloaded neo4j-community to run it from the command line on OSX.

I navigated to the neo4j-community folder and tried to run the first database with the following command:

```
sudo bin/neo4j -console -path Neo4j\ Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-1/installation-3.5.5
```

Now it starts a db, however it is not the db specified: first of all it is empty and secondly it is not using the custom ports specified in the configuration file.

How to run a neo4j graph database created with Neo4j Destop with the `bin/neo4j` command line executable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [neo4j console how to specify local path of existing db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700718/neo4j-console-how-to-specify-local-path-of-existing-db)

Comment: Hi @logisima, actually this question was asked before the other. So it should be the other a duplicate of this. They are little different because in this one I am asking how to run two db at the same time, the other is more focused on the path.