# neo4j console how to specify local path of existing db?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

Suppose I have a graph database created with Neo4j Desktop in the path

```
path/neo4jDatabases/database-abc/installation-3.5.5
```

In a different path I have the `neo4j-community-3.5.5` folder (I am on OSX). I am trying to start the `path/neo4jDatabases/database-abc/installation-3.5.5` database with neo4j-community.

I am trying this command:

```
sudo ./bin/neo4j console -path path/neo4jDatabases/database-abc/installation-3.5.5
```

but the started database is using the directories of `neo4j-community-3.5.5` instead of the ones specified in the path.

How can I start neo4j-community using the path of an existing db (created with Neo4j Desktop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `path` argument doesn't exist for the command `neo4j`.
If you want to change the data folder location of your community server, you need to modify the configuration of your community server (the `conf/neo4j.conf`) by specifying the `dbms.directories.data` property :

```
dbms.directories.data=path/neo4jDatabases/database-abc/installation-3.5.5/data
```

Cheers.

Comment: Suppose I want to run 2 db at different ports at the same time. The stupid solution would be to duplicate the `neo4j-community-3.5.5` folder and set different properties. Is there a smarter solution?

Comment: For the moment, you don't have other solutions. In the next major version, Neo4j will be multi-tenant.

Comment: Should I change `dbms.directories.active_database` to `path/neo4jDatabases/database-abc/installation-3.5.5/data/databases/graph.db` too or being inside `data` folder it's automatically changed??

Comment: for the `active_database` do nothing ! (except if you want to change the name of the `graph.db` folder)